# How to put a direction arrow on Y and X axis of a ChartJS graph

Tags: javascript, charts

[image]

How can I add direction arrow on Y and X axis of a ChartJS graph. Any one with an idea advice whether it's possible or not and how.

Here is code for drawing the chart.

```
    var ctx = $("#mycanvas");

        var LineGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'line',
            data: chartdata});
```

Bs

Answer (score 0):

Try this out.. Not sure whether this will meet your requirement or not

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="800" height="400"></canvas>

Chart.types.Line.extend({
    name: "LineAlt",
    draw: function () {
        Chart.types.Line.prototype.draw.apply(this, arguments);

        var ctx = this.chart.ctx;
        ctx.save();
        // text alignment and color
        ctx.textAlign = "center";
        ctx.textBaseline = "bottom";
        ctx.fillStyle = this.options.scaleFontColor;
        // position
        var x = this.scale.xScalePaddingLeft * 0.4;
        var y = this.chart.height / 2;
        // change origin
        ctx.translate(x, y)
        // rotate text
        ctx.rotate(-90 * Math.PI / 180);
        ctx.fillText(this.datasets[0].label, 0, 0);
        ctx.restore();
    }
});

var data = {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "My First dataset",
            fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
        },
        {
            label: "My Second dataset",
            fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
        }
    ]
};

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx).LineAlt(data, {
    // make enough space on the right side of the graph
    scaleLabel: "          <%=value%>"
});
```